# BeautifulSoup - How to remove nested tags with no text and blank space from the end of HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to remove tags that have no text inside of them. For example I have the following tags:

```
<p>
   <p>
       <br/>
   </p>
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
   <br/>
</p>
```

I have the following function:

```
@staticmethod
def stripTagWithNoText(soup,tagname,**kwargs):
    """Strip tags with no text"""
    #Make sure that soup and tags were defined
    assert isinstance(tagname,str)

    #Remove tags with no text
    for tag in soup.find_all(tagname):
        if tag.string:
            continue
        for subtag in tag.findChildren():
            if subtag.string:
                break
        else:
            continue
        tag.extract()
```

However this is also removing tags such as the following:

```
<p>This is some random text</p>
```

Can anyone spot what is wrong with this?

Additionally, suppose I have the following appended to the end of my html:

```
<p><br />
</p><p><br /> 
</p><p><br />
</p><p><br /> 
</p><p><br />
</p><p><br />
</p>
```

Is there someway to remove all blank spaces from the end of the html similar to string_text.strip()?

**Note**
I am using Python3, bs4

Comment: It would be helpful to know if its bs3 or 4... python 2 or 3.

Comment: I am using Python3, bs4

Comment: If the answer doesnt work for you, post the html in question so i can use a real test case.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

def main():
    test = """
    <p>
    this should not be here
       <p>this should not be here
           <br/>this should not be here
       </p>
       this should not be here
    </p>
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(test, 'html.parser')

    def stripTagWithNoText(soup, tagname):
        def remove(node):
            for index, item in enumerate(node.contents):
                if isinstance(item, Tag):
                    remove(node.contents[index])
                else:
                    node.contents[index] = ''

        #Remove tags with no text
        for tag in soup.find_all(tagname):
            remove(tag)
        print(soup)

    stripTagWithNoText(soup, 'p')
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```